# Is it safe to update iOS test device to latest dot release of iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, ios8.4

In general, I'd like to know if it's safe to apply dot releases of iOS to my test devices (i.e. it won't break my ability to build to the device.) In this particular case my iPod Touch is running iOS 8.4 and I'm wondering if I can update to 8.4.1. I have Xcode 6.4 with iOS SDK 8.4, which is the latest stable release at this time of writing. In the past, when I've updated iOS by a major version number this has forced me to update Xcode to get the latest iOS SDK, and I was wondering if this is also a concern with minor versions.

Comment: generally you should update to the latest stable version and test your app on that regardless of if you'll have to update Xcode

Comment: Right, my only concern is that there doesn't appear to be an SDK for 8.4.1, and I wasn't sure if that's needed or of the 8.4 SDK will work for all 8.4.x releases.

Comment: I doubt Apple would do something like release an iOS update that you couldn't develop for with the latest Xcode.

Comment: @danielcg: indeed, I have never seen such a thing happen, and I'm developing iOS apps since iOS 5

Comment: That sounds reasonable, I'm just a bit skittish as i've had my device become ineligible in the past. If you're confident go ahead and submit an answer and I'll accept it. (And test if the update works!)

Comment: I tried to answer "Yes!" to your question, but I got an error message saying "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 4." ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple wouldn't release an iOS update that you couldn't develop for with the latest version of Xcode. To be safe, check for Xcode updates to make sure you're on the latest version before updating your device. :)